# Can multiple routers be register at once in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I have found in the documentation that routers are registered like this:

```
app.include_router(router1)
app.include_router(router2)
```

but this seems unnecessarily verbose if I jut want to include a list of routers (like if i have 100 i have to repeat this 100 times? Is there a way to pass them in a list or something?Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Iterate over a sequence of `routers`

### Simple for loop

You can use a for loop with the list of the routers you want:

```py
for router in router1, router2, router3:
    account.include_router(router)
```

You would still need to make a list that contains all your routers, one way or another, however.

If you want to store the sequence outside the for loop, it's recommended to use a tuple instead of a list for simplicity of data-structures:

```py
routers = router1, router2, router3

for router in routers:
    account.include_router(router)
```

### Function to extract fastapi.APIRouter from a module

If you have a great number of routes, you can do something like this, assuming they are in a single module, but you can adapt it to multiple modules :

```py
def include_router_from_module(target, module):
    module_attributes = vars(module)
    
    for attribute in module_attributes.values():
        if isinstance(attribute, fastapi.APIRouter):
            target.include_router(attribute)

include_router_from_module(app, your_module)
```

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't require updating the main file to include added routers to a module.

Comment: i like the second option for automating the process upvoted it. The loop yes it is the obvious way to avoid multiple lines but I was looking more for a built in solution from fast-api this seems like a thing they should have made easier with decorators or an automation.

Answer (score 1):

## No, there is no builtin for bulk include routers

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77445628/can-multiple-routers-be-register-at-once-in-fastapi/77459850#comment136556192_77445833):

> I was looking more for a built in solution from fast-api

There is **no** FastAPI builtin method to include routers en masse.
We can see in the [FastAPI reference documentation about FastAPI()](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/reference/fastapi/#fastapi.FastAPI) class that there is no such method.

So the answer to your question is: **"No".**

If you seek handmade alternatives/recipes for implementing such method, see other answers for that (the [most upvotes one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77445833/6251742) from @Loïc Ribere has a great one with the `include_router_from_module` function).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include multiple routers at once by iterating through a list of routers. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

routers = [router1, router2, router3, ..., router100]

for router in routers:
    app.include_router(router)
```

With this approach, you can easily register all your routers with a simple loop.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can use a for loop.

```py
for router in routers:
    app.include_router(router)
```